# Modes of Convergence, Real Analysis ch 2 problem 36

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, elementary-set-theory, lp-spaces

If $\mu(E_n) < \infty$ for $n\in\mathbb{N}$ and $1_{E_n}\rightarrow f$ in $L^{1}$, then $f$ is (a.e. equal to) the characteristic function of a measurable set.

I am not sure how to define $E_n$ in order to prove this, any suggestions is greatly appreciated.

Comment: *You* don't define the $E_n$, they're given: any sequence of measurable sets whose characteristic functions converge in $L^1$.

Comment: Convergence in $L^1$ implies a subsequence that converges pointwise a.e.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $1_{E_n}\rightarrow f$ in $L^{1}$
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{E_n}|1_{E_n}-f|d\mu=0
$$
So for any $\epsilon>0$, there is a $n$ that
$$
\int_{E_n}|1_{E_n}-f|d\mu<\frac{\epsilon}{2^n}
$$
Let $F_k=\bigcup_{n=k}^{\infty}E_n$. Then
$$
\int_{F_k}|1_{F_k}-f|d\mu\leqslant \sum_{n=k}^{\infty}\int_{E_n}|1_{E_n}-f|d\mu<\frac{\epsilon}{2^k}
$$
Clearly $F_1\supset\cdots \supset F_k\cdots$. So let $F=\bigcap_{k=1}^{\infty}F_k$ and by monotone class theorem
$$
\int_{F}|1_{F}-f|d\mu=\lim_{k\to\infty}\int_{F_k}|1_{F_k}-f|d\mu=0
$$

So $f=1_{F}$ a.e.

Comment: Actually, there is a possibility that $F$ is a null set.

You should have proved that 
$\int_X |1_F-f|d\mu =0$

Comment: $F$ being null set won't matter for domain of integral can be null set

Comment: You are right! But then every functions are equal a.e.  In order to say that $f=1_F$ a.e, the domain of integral in the last equation should be X.

Comment: What is $X$ you are talking about? $F$ is clearly defined.

Comment: I mean..  by say that $\int_F|1_F-f|d\mu=0$ as your last argument, we can only conclude that $1_F=f$ a.e on $F$ not on whole set which I meant $X$

Comment: Oh I see. $f=0$ outside $F$ is implied by meaning of $1_F$.

Comment: How does the meaning of $1_F$ implies that $f=0$ outside $F$?

Comment: Since $1_{E_n}\rightarrow f$ in $L^{1}$, $\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{E_n}|1_{E_n}-f|d\mu=0$. Outside each $E_n$, $f=0$

Comment: More precisely, on each $E_n^c$, $f=0$. So $f=0$ on $\bigcup E_n^c=F^c$

Comment: We don't know if $E_n$ is disjoint but consider that they are disjoint since we have a freedom. Let $f=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n}1_{E_n}$. Then $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\int_{E_n}|1_{E_n}-f|=0$ but $f\neq 0$ outside each $E_n$

Comment: Sorry, that example does not work

Comment: If $\mu$ is finite, we can consider $f=1_X$. And it satisfies $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\int_{E_n}|1_{E_n}-f|=0$ but $f\neq 0$ outside each $E_n$

Comment: It should be on $E_n^c$, $f=0$ a.e.

Comment: We don’t have any restriction on the space. Thus, it should be true on finite space too.

Comment: In your case, $E_n\to X$ in measure. So $f=0$ a.e

Comment: Of course, it is to

Comment: I was giving counter example for your argument which is that if $lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \int_{E_n}|1_E_n -f|d\mu=0$, then $f=0$ on $E_n^c$.

Comment: Yes, I know. I mean that in your example, $\mu(E_n)\to \mu(X)$. So $\mu(\{x:f(x)\neq 0\})=0$. So $f=0$ a.e

Comment: Yes, that is true but the fact that $\mu(\{x:f(x) \neq 0 \})=0$ is just clear from the setting that $f=1_X$

Comment: So it seems your proof does not work :(

Comment: This doesn't work. Consider $E_n = \bigl[\frac{1}{n}, 1 + \frac{1}{n}\bigr]$ for $n \geqslant 1$, then $1_{E_n} \to 1_{(0,1]}$, but $\bigcup E_n = (0,2]$ (and $\bigcap E_n = \{1\}$). You need to consider $F^+ = \bigcap_{k = 1}^{\infty} \bigcup_{n = k}^{\infty} E_n$ or $F^- = \bigcup_{k = 1}^{\infty} \bigcap_{n = k}^{\infty} E_n$. Or use the fact that a subsequence converges almost everywhere.

Comment: Thanks, @ Daniel Fischer

Comment: I can't see why the second display holds. We only have $\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{E_n}|1_{E_n}-f|d\mu=0$. But the second display means $\lim_{n\to\infty}2^n\int_{E_n}|1_{E_n}-f|d\mu=0$.

Comment: By the definition of $\epsilon-N$ formula.